# List .NET objects inside an object

Tags: c#, powershell

I don't know how can I access objects inside an object. Everything I read is about the `Get-Member` option, but that is in order to listing the methods/property, not the classes inside a class, it seems like it is taken for granted or you should know it or something.

I want to get the classes inside `System.Net`, or whatever class I want to be listed:

- `WebRequest`
- `Sockets`
- `WebClient`
- …

I already know that I can be shown the methods inside with

```
[System.Net.WebRequest] | gm -Static
```

or without `-Static` for the general methods.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you want to enumerate the classes in a namespace? Nested objects in an actual object?

Comment: I guess he mistakes namespaces for classes but I am not sure :)

Comment: List .NET objects inside *a namespace*?

Comment: given `System.Net` which I guess it's a namespace, I want to get `WebRequest`, `Sockets` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | 
    % { $_.GetTypes() } |
    ? { $_.IsPublic -and $_.Namespace -ne $null -and $_.Namespace.StartsWith("System.Net")
```

Of course you can alter the filtering according to your needs and add sorting if necessary

Comment: If you omit `-and $_.IsClass` you get some `enum` types as well. Something like `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | % { $_.GetTypes() } | ? { $_.IsPublic -and $_.Namespace -eq "System.Net" }`

Comment: Yeah therefore I wrote he can alter the filtering to his needs. But as he asked "I want to get the classes inside System.Net..." I wrote the example in a way to filter for that

Comment: I note that `Sockets` which the asker lists, is not a type but a nested namespace. So maybe he wants `| ? { $_.IsPublic -and $_.Namespace -ne $null -and $_.Namespace.StartsWith("System.Net") }`.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way¿?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Seems you guessed right :) Took your suggestion - thx!

Comment: IMHO the pipeline is not that complex but if you are looking like something similar to Get-Member for that I guess you are out of luck. But one could easily write a cmdlet for that or maybe there even is already one in PSGallery etc.

Comment: Clearly, this finds a type exactly if its assembly is in the current app domain. Probably that is fine. But you could find more or fewer types than expected. To search only a single assembly (in this case `System.dll`), you can use `[System.Net.WebRequest].Assembly.GetTypes() | ? { $_.IsPublic -and $_.Namespace -ne $null -and $_.Namespace.StartsWith("System.Net") }`.